# Salesforce LWC - State management in checkbox input control

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lwc-dom, lwc-jest

I am new to salesforce LWC. Developing a page with a checkbox inside a component. So my task is to maintain the state of the checkbox even after the page refresh. For this, I used session management to store those checked values and was able to retrieve them as well. Now how can I bind these values stored in the session back to the input control?

I am using input control to create the checkbox with key and value attributes as below.

HTML:

```
<input key={keyname} value={value} type="checkbox" onclick={changeHandler} >
```

Is there any onload function we can use in the above input html tag to write something like the below?

```
onload(){
foreach (element in session storage) {
this.template.querySelector('input').checked = true;
}
```

///////////

c_comp.html

```
<template >
                                <template for:each={inputs} for:item="input">        
                                    <tr key={input.label}> 
                                        <td>
                                                <div>{input.value} {input.label}</div>  
                                            
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input 
                                            key={input.label} 
                                            value={input.value} 
                                            type="checkbox" 
                                            id={input.name}
                                            name={input.name}
                                            onclick={changeHandler} 
                                            checked={input.checked} >
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </template>
                            </template>
```

c_comp.js

```
@api inputs
@api tempVar

changeHandler(event){
    this.tempVar  = this.inputs;
    this.tempVar.find((input)=>input.name === event.target.name).checked = event.target.checked;
    sessionStorage.setItem(event.target.name, event.target.checked);
}

connectedCallback(){
        this.inputs.forEach((input)=>input.checked = sessionStorage.getItem(input.name) == 'true');

}
```

callig component html:

```
<c-comp inputs={t_option}></c-comp>
```

calling component .js

```
t_option = [
    { name: 'v1', label: 'label1', value:'value1' },
    { name: 'v2', label: 'label2', value:'value2'},
    { name: 'v3', label: 'label3', value:'value3'},
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `connectedCallback` to do things you want to do "onload." As a trivial example:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  inputs = [
    { name: 'v1' },
    { name: 'v2' },
    { name: 'v3' },
  ]
  connectedCallback() {
    this.inputs.forEach((input)=>input.checked = sessionStorage.getItem(input.name) == 'true');
  }
  save(event) {
    this.inputs.find((input)=>input.name === event.target.name).checked = event.target.checked;
    sessionStorage.setItem(event.target.name, event.target.checked);
  }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    Values:
    <template for:each={inputs} for:item="input">
    <div key={input.name}>
    <input 
        type="checkbox" 
        checked={input.checked} 
        onchange={save}
        id={input.name}
        name={input.name} />
        <label for={input.name}>{input.name}</label>
    </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

---

Edit:

For an `@api` variable, you can't modify the objects. Simply assigning the object to a new variable doesn't make a new copy. Instead, you can copy the values with a getter/setter pair:

```
#inputs = [];
@api set inputs(value) {
  if(value) {
    this.#inputs = value.map((v) => ({ ...v }));
  } else {
    this.#inputs = [];
}
get inputs(value) {
  return this.#inputs.map((v) => ({ ...v }));
}
```

Now, you can set those values as you like:

```
  connectedCallback() {
    this.#inputs.forEach((input)=>input.checked = sessionStorage.getItem(input.name) == 'true');
  }
  save(event) {
    this.#inputs.find((input)=>input.name === event.target.name).checked = event.target.checked;
    sessionStorage.setItem(event.target.name, event.target.checked);
  }
```

Note that `#` means the variable is private to the class.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/salesforce-lwc-4hntpx).

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have configured this but seeing an issue as below.[Invalid mutation: Cannot set "checked" on "[object Object]". "[object Object]" is read-only.] Do you think something else is missing in my case as i am getting the inputs from other page. This issue is happening when i check the box from UI. And my inputs have multiple key value pairs. like in your example it is one pair but i have multiple(3 pairs)

Comment: when i try to print this.input -> it returns me Proxy {}

Comment: @monk It sounds like you're getting the values through an `@api` attribute. Those are read-only; you'll need to copy the values to something you can mutate, or send the data to the parent component so it can store the data, instead. I would need to see more code to help further.

Comment: it still gives me [object Object] error

Comment: @monk You have to actually copy the object. Simply assigning to a new variable doesn't remove the read-only protection. See my edit.